# Doctrine LIMIT Syntax Error?

Tags: mysql, doctrine

```
'[Syntax Error] line 0, col 71: Error: Expected end of string, got 'LIMIT''
```

Here's my code:

```
public function getLatestChapters()
    {
        return $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT c, m FROM models\Chapter c JOIN c.Manga m ORDER BY c.CreateDate LIMIT 10')->getResult();
    }
```

What could posibly the problem for this? How can I use LIMIT in Doctrine?

I am using Doctrine 2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like there is [no](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-23?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) LIMIT/OFFSET in [DQL anymore](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/a96f5caf19d21cb6?fwc=1&pli=1).

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
//.. build your query
$q = $qb->getQuery();
$q->setFirstResult($offset);
$q->setMaxResults($limit);
$result = $q->getResult();
```

Answer (score 4):

I would Like to Contribute to this post and want to tell people that If you want to use DBAL with limit in your Unit Tests you can use following:

```
$client = static::createClient()
$em = $client->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('WRITE YOUR QUERY HERE');
$query->setFirstResult(0);
$query->setMaxResults(1);
$data = $query->getResult();
```

Same code can be used in controller also with some modifications :)